# Counterup JS to work

Tags: theming, 8

According to Counter Js**Include**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
```

(I've defined the library in the theme.libraries.yml and attached the library in the theme.info.yml and it shows in the header)

```
statcounter:
 version: 8.x-1.0
js:
 scripts/jquery.counterup.min.js: { minified: true }
dependencies:
 - core/jquery
```

[image]

**HTML**

```
<span class="counter">1,234,567.00</span>
<span>$</span><span class="counter">1.99</span>
<span class="counter">12345</span>
```

(Have added this in a block in the front page and the markup is displayed)

**jQuery**

```
$('.counter').counterUp(); **or with extra parameters**
$('.counter').counterUp({
delay: 10,
time: 1000
});
```

(Have placed the jquery in a separate custom js; and defined it in the theme, the js is loaded and no errors till now)

```
   custom:
    version: 8.x-1.0
   js:
    scripts/custom.js: {}
```

I want to attach the last bit of jquery to the theme and make the counter work...Any ideas how to get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: can you show the library definition ? the path seems wrong, should be like libraries/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js

Comment: @remy edited to add library defnition

Comment: ok - so the file is in your theme, is it really there ? no 404 ? your custom js is loaded too on the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all files are present !

The drupal way for custom js in your theme is a [behavoir](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515), so your js file should look like this:

```
    (function ($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.myThemeBehavior = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
           $(context).find('.counter').once('myThemeCounter').counterUp({
             delay: 10,
             time: 1000
           });  
        }
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

This will ensure the script is executed after the DOM is loaded and only will run once.

Comment: Worked great.... Thanks for you time. Helped me a lot :)